# Chronologically order two log files into one

Tags: logging, merge, timestamp, combine

I have two log files.

In these logs the format is something like

```
15:41:52,236 INFO
```

And then followed by the actual log messages.

If I have two files which can have timestamps that occur before or after another, how can I combine the two files into one?

Is there a way with simple tools so I won't have to go write a program to do this? I really just need a quick way to see the sequence of events.

Also I need to account for the fact that there may be a few, limited number of lines that do not have a timestamp.

Comment: It would help to know which OS you're using to give you an exact answer. In both Windows / *nix, you should be able to do this easily with output redirection and sorting from the command line. This is all assuming the timestamps are formatted the same way and each line is either blank or contains a timestamp.

Comment: Here's my 1 line windows example: type file1.txt > file3.txt & type file2.txt >> file3.txt & type file3.txt | sort | more

Comment: @BrianC. Thanks, I was fixed on doing this a more complicated way and overlooked just appending one file to the other. If you want you can turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know which OS you're using to give you an exact answer. In both Windows / *nix, you should be able to do this easily with output redirection and sorting from the command line. This is all assuming the timestamps are formatted the same way and each line is either blank or contains a timestamp.

Here's my 1 line windows example: type file1.txt > file3.txt & type file2.txt >> file3.txt & type file3.txt | sort | more

Answer (score 0):

> how can I combine the two files into one?

Easy. E.g.

- open file 1 in a text editor.
- append file2
- <strike>profit</strike> done!
- Or `cat file1 file2 > file_with_both`
- Or `type copy file1 file2 file_with_both`

Next: Now that you have one file: How do you sort it?
The anser is surprisingly simple: user the `sort` program.